# Manipulate Cookie Headers in C#

Tags: c#, cookies, web-scraping

I am currently scraping e-commerce websites to get prices and other product related information, I am from the Philippines and some of the sites I scrape would give me prices in PH, some in USD, I need to be able to download the US version of the site so I could get the prices in USD.

For instance, there's this site that has URL_COUNTRY in the response header, it returns NULL ( URL_COUNTRY=(null) ) when I switch my country to USA, but when I set it to other countries it would return URL_COUNTRY=ph (for Phils) and when I get the XPATH for the price it would give me the the PESO value even if I passed the USA url.

**UPDATE**
I tried the following but to no avail:

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("URL_COUNTRY", "us"));
cookieContainer.Add(new Uri(url), new Cookie("URL_LANGUAGE", "en"));
webRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
```

How do I manipulate the headers so I could get the US page?

Answer (score 0):

Try HttpClient.
Something like this should do:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com/");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
}
```

Comment: thank you, I'm using HttpWebRequest and CookieContainer for this, do you have an idea for that?